# Spring-Boot template resolution fails when WAR is deployed

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot, war, thymeleaf

My Spring-Boot app works fine when running it via the Eclipse IDE (with S.T.S. 3.8.4 installed), with the embedded tomcat server.

I packaged it as a WAR and deployed it to a local Tomcat server.

When accessing the app, a blank page is returned. I discovered the exception in the Tomcat logs (on Windows, `C:\<path-to-tomcat>\logs`) An exception is thrown when trying to resolve the Thymeleaf templates:

```
2017-04-04 12:33:36.602 ERROR 5724 --- [io-12080-exec-7] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-12080-exec-7] Exception processing template "home": Error resolving template "common/layout", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (template: "home" - line 5, col 7)

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "common/layout", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (template: "home" - line 5, col 7)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:865) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the casing of the folder names.

I had my layout fragment in `templates/Common/layout.html` (notice the capital C in Common) and in my views was referencing `common/layout`, which worked within the IDE, but did not work when deploying a WAR on a Tomcat server. Maybe because the IDE ignores casing, and Tomcat is case sensitive?

It worked after changing the reference in my view to the correct casing of the folder, `Common/layout`